# serialize/deserialize & modify data

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that pulls serialized php data from a database, unserializes it, modifies the data, then serializes it again. What I would like to do is modify the name & pet fields (as indicated below) but can't figure out how to access individual fields to modify them:

```
use PHP::Serialization qw(serialize unserialize);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); 

###blah, blah, blah
while ( @a = $sth->fetchrow() ){
my $hashref = unserialize( $a[0] );
print Dumper($hashref); 
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$VAR1 = [
      bless( {
               'name' => 'Fred', # I want this to be Dave
               'pet' => 'Cat',  # I want this to be Dog
               'date' => '1977'
             }, 'PHP::Serialization::Object::stdClass' ),
      bless( {
              'name' => 'Mary', # I want this to be Jane
               'pet' => 'Worm', # I want this to be Pig
               'date' => '1977'
             }, 'PHP::Serialization::Object::stdClass' )
    ];
```

UPDATE:
Thx to Hugmeir, I have the following, which seems to work. Is this the best way to change the 'name' if I don't know the index number?

```
for my $hashref (@{$array_ref}) {

        if ( $hashref->{name} =~ /Mary/ ){
          $hashref->{name} = 'Jane'; 
         }

}
```

Comment: If you want to change Mary to Jane, you are better off saying `$hashref->{name} eq 'Mary'`; the pattern match will also result in  Maryjo or RoseMary changing to Jane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, that's not a hashref - It's an arrayref that holds two elements, each a hashref*. This breaks PHP::Serialization's encapsulation, but should do the trick:

```
my $array_ref = unserialize( $a[0] );

for my $hashref (@{$array_ref}) {
    @{$hashref}{qw(name pet)} = ('New name', 'New Pet');
    #Or $hashref->{name} = 'new name'; If you don't like slices.
}
```

EDIT: If you only wanted to modify, say, the first element, you could do

```
$array_ref->[0]->{name} = 'etc';
```

*Technically two hashrefs blessed to PHP::Serialization objects.

Comment: PHP::Serialization doesn't have encapsulation there; it's just blessing php objects into "PHP::Serialization::Object::" followed by the PHP object name (though the prefix can be changed in the decode/unserialize call); there are no such actual Perl classes.

Comment: `$array_ref->[0]{name}` also works; see the invaluable http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: thx, your suggestion works. How do I update 'Jane' if I don't know the index number? I believe I've got it but is there a better solution? (see my attempt above).

Comment: @ysth: As usual, I wish I could double ++ you. @usernumbermess: Here's another way to do it: `$_->{name} = 'Jane' for grep { $_->{name} eq 'Mary' } @$array_ref;` Or with a map: `map { $_->{name} = 'Jane' if $_->{name} eq 'Mary' } @$hashref;`

Comment: Whoops. I meant @$array_ref in the map example.